# Prove that the set of all the diagonal matrices is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

My attempt:

1) (closed under addition)

$\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \ddots &\hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation} + $ $\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\alpha & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \alpha & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \ddots &\hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \alpha & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \alpha \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}$ $=\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\epsilon + \alpha & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \epsilon + \alpha & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \ddots &\hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon + \alpha & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon + \alpha \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}$

2) Closed under multiplication by scalar

$\begin{equation}
 \lambda \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \ddots &\hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \epsilon \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation} $ $\begin{equation}
= \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\lambda\epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \lambda\epsilon & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \ddots &\hfill & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \lambda\epsilon & \hfill \\
\hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill & \lambda\epsilon \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation} $

Both are also diagonal matrices. 
But, do I need also to prove that they obey all the axioms of the vector space?

Comment: You could just notice that there is a isomorphism between diagonal matrices and vectors...

Comment: You only have multiples of the identity.  $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&2\end{array}\right)$ is also diagonal.  It depends which year you are in whether you have to prove the rest of the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have proved that a scalar multiple of a diagonal matrix, as well as the sum of two diagonal matrices is again a diagonal matrix, and finally that the zero matrix is a diagonal matrix, you have proved that the diagonal matrices are a sub-vector space of the space of all matrices. In particular, that tells you that the space is itself a vector space. But really, you should prove (or have proved) that a subspace with the above definition is always a vector space itself.